# Printing integers in a list as double digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of integers that I need to print out as a matrix. I did that as following:

```
    matrix = [mylist[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]
    for nlist in matrix:
        print(nlist)
```

This works well; for example if my list is [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and n is 3, it will output:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

Now I don't just want those integers, I want a zero in front of them; so 01 02 03 etc. I read that this is easily done with `print("{:0=2d}".format(integer))` , but it doesn't seem to work on my list or matrix. `print("{:0=2d}".format(mylist))` or `print("{:0=2d}".format(nlist))` gives me an error message.

How can I make it work for a list?

*Also, a very small thing I hope I'm allowed to ask here: how do I get rid of the square brackets around my matrix?*

EDIT: I figured out why my code didn't work. I had this if statement that said that if the program encountered a 0, that zero had to be printed as a string "X". So sometimes I would have a list of both integers and a string. Like so:

```
08 07 06
05 04 03
02 01  X
```

Should I just convert everything to a string then? Or how can I make it work?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to add a zero is to specify them all as strings. Then also to get rid of the brackets you will have to print each number separately.

```
for nlist in matrix:
    for value in nlist:
        print("0" + str(value), end=" ")
    print("")
```

Comment: You do not need to convert it to string explicitly

Comment: @yklsga yes but it makes the code more useful with it because it makes it more generic

Comment: You can do `print('0',value,sep='',end=' ')`

Comment: For more, view my answer below :)

Comment: Of course, I am saying this would suffice in this case @13ros27

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3] 
>>> " ".join(list(map(lambda x : "{:0=2d}".format(x), l)))
'01 02 03'
```

with no brackets, so try...

```
matrix = [mylist[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]
for nlist in matrix:
    print(" ".join(list(map(lambda x : "{:0=2d}".format(x), nlist))))
```

**edit**

With the mixed lists you can change the lambda a little like this,

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,'x',6],[7,8,9]]
>>> for nlist in matrix:
...     print(" ".join(list(map(lambda x: "{:0=2d}".format(x) if isinstance(x,int) else x, nlist))))
... 
01 02 03
04 x 06
07 08 09
```

Comment: You really don't need the lambda ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm getting a `ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'` error. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: @Rose you're passing in strings not int in your list?

Comment: They are supposed to be integers yes, but I probably messed up somewhere and made them strings haha. I'll look into it.

Comment: @corn3lius Let me be more specific: `"{:0=2d}".format` is a perfectly good function object which you can pass directly to `map`. Try `" ".join(list(map("{:0=2d}".format, l)))`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Supporting new condition that `0`'s should print as `X` and wrapping parens around `print` for python 3.x.

Suppose your integers are stored in a list `l`.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]  
n = 3

for i in range(n):
    print(" ".join(["{:0=2d}".format(x) if x != 0 else ' X' for x in l[n*i:n*(i+1)]]))
```

Output:

```
01 02 03
04 05 06
07 08  X
```

The explanation is that we loop through the list `l` in groups of `n` elements at a time (`l[n*i:n*(i+1)]`) (let's call this a sublist). Then, we format each element of the sublist, we apply the format function to convert it to a string as you want. Finally join the formatted sublist together with spaces and print.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
matrix = [mylist[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]
for nlist in matrix:
    mstr = ''
    for i in nlist:
        mstr += "{:0=2d} ".format(i)
    print(mstr)
```

Will give you

```
01 02 03 
04 05 06 
07 08 09
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is a **list of lists**. So when you are doing

```
for nlist in matrix:
        print(nlist)
```

The nlist would be list and you are printing it directly without *unpacking*. So if you want to avoid the brackets, you can just do `print(*nlist)`. For more on that, refer to [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/4410922).

If you want to add `0`'s in front of every element, you can utilize the parameters of print function like `sep` and `end`. This will work whether the element is `int` or `str`

```
matrix = [mylist[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]
for nlist in matrix:
    for item in nlist:
      print('0',item,sep='',end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: FYI : that functionality in print is a 3.x only solution. I did see he tagged it as such.

Comment: Yep, that's why this solution would do @corn3lius